# C free() allocated memory twice, will it cause segfault?

Tags: c, malloc

If we twice free() the same char pointer which is allocated with malloc(), will it cause segfalut?

```
void Allocate() 
{     
   char *y;
   y = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * 200);    
   free (y);
   strcpy(y,"helloworld");
   free (y);
}

int main()
{
     Allocate();
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I checked it doesn't dump core.

Comment: @mangusta: A self-check validates something for a particular compiler during a particular moon-phase. Sometimes that is enough; other times it's best to check the Standard (or SO).

Answer (score 2):

It's undefined behavior, so don't do it.

Even more, don't *use* the memory after calling `free()` in it, this is a total no-no:

```
free (y);
strcpy(y,"helloworld");
```

The above is *also* undefined behavior.

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: In my application i got core dump but in this example code i didn't get core dump.

Comment: @Jeyamaran Yes, that's because of *undefined* behavior. You cannot depend on getting any particular result. It's *undefined*. Clear?

Comment: Oh but some situation surely it will create core dump correct.

Answer (score 0):

Freeing the same memory twice will result in undefined behaviour, as will writing to memory which has been freed (see the `strcpy`).

The C Standard defines Undefined Behaviour in Section §1.3.12 as

> behaviour, such as might arise upon use of an erroneous program construct or erroneous data, for which this International Standard imposes no requirements [3].
>
> Undefined behaviour may also be expected when this International Standard omits the description of any explicit definition of behavior.
>
> (3) = permissible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the environment (with or with- out the issuance of a diagnostic message), to terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message).

As to what's happening I would guess the following:

1. You free `y`
2. You then `strcpy` over what was once `y` which may corrupt the heap; this itself is unlikely to segfault, but might (see above)
3. You then allocate `z`, which uses the possibly corrupted heap, and may segfault or misallocate the memory (i.e. return an address which cannot be used).
4. You then `strcpy` into a possibly misallocated bit of memory and thus may segfault.
5. You then free `y` again, with a heap which is possibly corrupt, which may segfault etc.

If you really want to know, use debug `libc` and `gdb` to find out.

Comment: Those thing i hv already knw. But i just need will it core dump at any situation.

Comment: The question says "will it cause segfalut" *(sic)*, not "will it core dump". Segfaults do not always cause a core dump. You will have to do (OS dependent) `ulimit -c unlimited` before running it to get a core dump.

Answer (score 0):

Freeing same pointer twice may cause heap corruption.  In your program after deallocating you are trying to copy a string which will cause segfault.

Comment: But i m not getting any core dump. I tried various way but i didn't get core dump even single time.

Comment: you may find here how to enable core dump. http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_enable_core.html

Comment: There's never going to be a guarantee that you'll get a core dump just because you're violating your program's memory.